# Django Error - ValueError: Cannot assign "'int": "row name" must be a "ForeignKey" instance

Tags: python, django, csv

i got this odd error and i don't know why.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'36'": "Ofac_Add.number" must be a "Ofac_Sdn" instance.
```

I created the Django Models and they work perfectly. Please find below my models:

```
class Ofac_Sdn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    b_i = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    programe= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_call_sign = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_type= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tonnage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_owner= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    dob_aka= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    #date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    #publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    #content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")



    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_sdn"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number,  self.name,  self.programe


class Ofac_Add(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    n= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    oras_zip = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    stat = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    # date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    # publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    # content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_add"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number, self.adresa ,  self.oras_zip


class Ofac_Alt(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    name_of_aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    # date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    # publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    # content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_alt"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number,  self.aka, self.name_of_aka
```

I have uploaded a bulk CSV file to my first model and now trying to upload the second CSV file to my second model which is in a relationship with the first one. When i did this, i got an error `*ValueError: Cannot assign "'36'": "Ofac_Add.number" must be a "Ofac_Sdn" instance.*` The rows from this CSV file look like this:

```
Number,N,Adresa,Oras,Stat,S
36,25,null,Havana,Cuba,null
```

The info from my first table is like this:

```
Number,Name,B/I,Program,More Info,Vessel CallSign,Vessel Type,Vessel DWT (Deadweight tonnage),Gross Registered Tonnage,Vessel Flag,Vessel Owner,DOB/AKA
36,AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES,null,CUBA,null,null,null,0,0,null,null,null
```

So the foreign key is there into the first table.
The import function is this one:

```
import csv, sys, os

project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/"

sys.path.append(project_dir)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django
django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add

data = csv.reader(open('/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/add.csv'),delimiter=",")
#data = csv.reader(open('/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/sdn2.csv'), dialect='excel-tab')
for row in data:

    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Add()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.n = row[1]
        post.adresa=row[2]
        post.oras=row[3]

        post.stat=row[4]
        post.s=row[5]

        post.save()
        #
        # try:
        #     int('')
        # except ValueError:
        #     pass
```

If someone could help, I would owe you a lot!

Thank you,
Cohen

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english I'm a foreigner.

You should change in the file where you read the csv
From

`post.number`

To
   `post.number_id`

Because **post.number** accept only **ofec_sdn** instances
And you assign a number who is the id.
And `ofec_sdn.number_id` is the row on db where django store the foreign keys

Comment: you rock my friend! this is it! where from you have learn this?

Comment: This is explained in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation
by the way I'm cohen as well :)

Comment: naim lakiotha ve todah raba ahi!

Comment: Samachti laazor gever